# Append div "n" times where "n" is value inside another html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a div that could contain different numbers inside it and a button.

When I click on this button, I want to **append divs according to the number in the div**, e.g. if I have number 1 then it should append 1 div, if I have number 2 it should append 2 divs, and so on.

I also want *each **appended div to have a unique id**.

What I have tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings('div').html() == '1') {
      $('body').append('<div>' + 'My div' + '</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  1
</div>

<button type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: So what is the question you are trying to ask then?

Comment: It's not appending because the `html()` does not equal `1` exactly.  There is whitespace.  You have to `.trim()` the html

Comment: @Taplar but the 1 is not static it's going to change, it could be 10 for example, i want to match the number of the divs with this number

Comment: I'm just pointing out that's why this logic is not working as you have it.

Comment: @MaryJane None of the current answers posted add a unique id to each appended div as wanted. Check the **pure JavaScript/jQuery** solution that I added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following ***pure JavaScript approach*** [[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/gj4a5psd/26/)] as well as ***jQuery approach*** [[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2dgj3nrk/12/)] to append divs with unique ids based on div value:

---

### Pure JavaScript:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var val = document.getElementById('val').textContent;
var idName = 1;

function addDiv(){
  var count = parseInt(val.trim());  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var appendDiv = document.createElement('div');
    appendDiv.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");
    appendDiv.setAttribute("id", "someId" + idName);
    document.body.appendChild(appendDiv);  
    idName++;
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', addDiv);
```

```css
.newDiv {background-color: red; margin: 5px auto; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="val">
  4
</div>

<button id="btn" type="button">Add</button>
```

---

### jQuery:

```js
var idName = 1;

$("button").on("click", function(){
  var count = parseInt($("#val").text().trim());
  
  for(let i=0; i < count; i++){
    $('body').append('<div class="newDiv" id="newDiv' + idName + '"></div>');
    idName++;
  }
})
```

```css
.newDiv {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="val">
  4
</div>

<button id="btn" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: You can also omit the `idName` variable and append the index to the id name too but I used the variable to illustrate how you can use just about anything to create unique IDs for the looped div.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could work for you:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').click(function() {
        var val = parseInt($(this).siblings('div').text().trim());
        for(let i=0; i < val; i++){
            $('body').append('<div>'+'TEST'+'</div>');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Fake news...it does not stop working if the button is clicked a second time...it works every time you click it. And the 'unique ID' requirement was added after this answer was provided. Nonetheless, I'm glad Mary Jane found the answer she needed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the white space that precedes or follows the element's content and you do that with `.trim()`.

You also need to be looking at only the previous sibling, not all the siblings because after you add one more div, it won't contain the number that the previous one does and the code will never find a match after that.

Lastly, you should use `.text()`, not `.html()` when you are looking at the text content of an element and not its HTML child content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // This is only added to demonstrate that the following 
  // code works no matter what the number is in the div
  let val = prompt("Pick a number");
  $("div")[0].textContent = " " + val + " ";
  // *****************************************************
  
  let div = $('button').prev();    // Get a reference to the <div> just prior to the button
  let num = +div.text().trim();    // Get the text content of that <div> and convert to number
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    // Loop the amount of times as was in the <div>
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      // Create a new <div> with an id of the current loop index
      $('body').append('<div id=' + i + '>' + 'My div' + '</div>');
    }
    
    // Show newly created code (scroll to bottom of results to see)
    console.log($("body").html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  
</div>

<button type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: `$('button')` and `$('div')` selector is not a very good practice since there could be more `div` blocks or another buttons.

Comment: @AntihypeBird Of course, but writing selectors isn't what the question is about and since I'm providing a simplified use case, there's no need to make it more complicated. This is very common when we answer questions.